# requirejs + r.js disable case sensitivity

Tags: requirejs

Is there a way/parameter that turns off case sensitivity in requirejs, for that matter is there a r.js switch to disable case sensitivity.

If i define a module in x.js
if i ask for it via `define('x',function(x){})` or `define('X',function(x){})` this will cause two objects in `requirejs.s.contexts._.defined[x and X]`
Is there a way to-lower all of this and not worry that someone will uppercase a character.

For that matter r.js minifies by walking the dependency tree is there a switch to make it not case sensitive so that i don't get two `define('x'...define('X'..`  modules in the minified output.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no flag or setting you can turn on to do this. And having read RequireJS' code, I think this would be a significant enterprise to make it case-insensitive. It would require more than just overriding a few functions here and there. This applies to `require.js` and `r.js`.

In an [old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/dj6Y6shYU-8), James Burke mentioned using `map` but that's not the same thing as case insensitivity.